# Are there any OO languages without inheritance?

Tags: object-oriented, programming-languages, inheritance

During a code review today, a colleague of mine said something interesting:

> `prototype` is only useful when you need inheritance - and *when's inheritance ever a good idea*?

I thought about this and I realised that I usually use inheritance to get around code that was badly designed in the first place. Modern OO style prefers composition over inheritance, but I don't know of any languages which have taken this to heart and actually *enforce* it.

Are there any general-purpose programming languages with classes, objects, methods, interfaces, and so on, which disallow class-based inheritance? (If such an idea doesn't make sense, why not?)

Comment: Your colleague has led you astray. The `prototype` is also useful for when you have public methods and properties that should be shared between instances. It's also useful because it allows you to properly use the `instanceof` operator in JavaScript: `if (foo instanceof Foo) { ...`.

Comment: I think we should make a distinction between the inheritance of type, state and behaviour. The preference of composition is very common in the Java community but at the same time, inheritance (and even multiple inheritance) of types is widely used and encouraged... and realized using the `implements` keyword and interfaces (as opposed to the inheritance of state and behaviour introduced with the use of the `extends` keyword on classes containing any implementation).

Comment: Preferring composition doesn't mean completely abandoning inheritance is a good idea.

Comment: see [Java without implementation inheritance](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/99869/31260): "Google's go is an example of a language which does away with implementation inheritance while being OOP..."

Comment: @GregBurghardt The same can be accomplished with a factory function which returns an object containing functions (storing private data in the closure). `new`, `this` and `prototype` are all too much of a minefield for common use IMO.

Comment: @Caleb There are plenty of techniques which have legitimate uses but are disallowed by mainstream languages: method swizzling, monkey-patching, multiple inheritance, `exec`... I'm not saying inheritance _should_ be abandoned altogether, I just want to know if anyone's tried to make it work and what it would look like.

Answer (score 18):

Setting aside the question of [the definition of object oriented programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DefinitionsForOo) the question becomes one of "are there languages which use composition only and have no tools for inheritance?"

The answer to this is quite simply "yes".  In go, there are no way to do inheritance as one classically thinks of it.  One *can* embedded an object in another object and the extend that object.  From [Object Desoriented Language](http://areyoufuckingcoding.me/2012/07/25/object-desoriented-language/) ([github mirror](https://github.com/nu7hatch/areyoufuckingcoding.me/blob/master/content/2012/07/25/object-desoriented-language.md)):

```
type Person struct {
        Name string
}

func (p *Person) Intro() string {
        return p.Name
}

type Woman struct {
        Person
}

func (w *Woman) Intro() string {
        return "Mrs. " + w.Person.Intro()
}
```

You've got a person struct that has a Name which is a String.  It has a public function called Intro which returns the name.  The Woman struct also has a function for Intro which accesses the strut embedded in it.  And so one can fulfill the intentions of inheritance by using composition only.

More on this can be seen at [GoLang Tutorials: Inheritance and subclassing in Go - or its near likeness](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.com/2011/06/inheritance-and-subclassing-in-go-or.html).

So yes, it is possible to have an OO language without inheritance, and one does exist.

Within go this is known as [embedding](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) and gives enclosing structures the ability to access the embedded fields and functions as if it had them too - but it's not a subclass.  The design philosophy can be found in the [Go FAQ: Why is there no type inheritance?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#inheritance)

Comment: One could also comment about the use of `typedef` and `struct` in C...

Comment: @cwallenpoole there are indeed similar ideas there, though I would hesitate to call C an object oriented language.

Comment: I dunno. I'll admit the fact that you can't create objects with functions attached does work against it, but without inheritance, OOP looses much of its flavor.

Comment: @cwallenpoole and we start getting into defining what inheritance is and object orientation.  But it *is* possible, its just a different way of thinking about the problem. The thing is that inheritance is the way most C++ and Java programers think of extension... but there are other models.  Extension without inheritance: [1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jn5/), [2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jn6/), [3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jn7/) are good reads.

Comment: The link to "Object Desoriented Language" is stuck in a redirect loop at the moment, but I found the article here: https://github.com/nu7hatch/areyoufuckingcoding.me/blob/master/content/2012/07/25/object-desoriented-language.md. Thanks!

Comment: @MattBrowne thank you for telling me. I've added the link to the mirror in the answer.

Comment: To clarify a few things while I'm here:

1. Methods in Go are largely syntax sugar to allow for `foo.method()` calling notation; however, you could equally write `Foo.method(foo)`. They do serve one other function which is to tell the type system what interfaces the type satisfies.

2. Struct embedding is just syntax sugar for creating methods on the outer struct which delegate directly to the same methods on the inner struct. You can do this in any language with methods, it will just take more boilerplate.

3. Typedef/struct in C is no analog since C doesn't have a notion of 'methods'

Answer (score 7):

> Are there any general-purpose programming languages with classes, objects, methods, interfaces, and so on, which disallow class-based inheritance?

This reads very much like a description of VBA - Visual Basic for Applications, embedded in Microsoft Office and other VBA-enabled hosts (e.g. AutoCAD, Sage 300 ERP, etc.), or even VB6. The "A" of "Basic" stands for "All-purpose" anyway, so there's the "general-purpose" part.

VB6/VBA has classes (and therefore objects), methods and interfaces - you could define an `ISomething` interface in a class module like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoSomething()
End Sub
```

And then have another class that does this:

```
Option Explicit
Implements ISomething

Private Sub ISomething_DoSomething()
    'implementation here
End Sub
```

Such a class, exposing no public members, could only ever be accessed via its `ISomething` interface - and there could very well be dozens of different implementations of `ISomething` out there, so OOP VBA code is perfectly capable of polymorphism, and it's perfectly legal for a given class to implement multiple interfaces, too.

VB6/VBA does not allow *class inheritance* however, so you can't inherit an *implementation* from another type, only its interface. Now, whether this is an accident, a design flaw, a stroke of genius or a huge ugly oversight is open for debate; it's not clear whether VB6/VBA *takes this to heart*, but it most definitely *enforces* it.

If [Go doesn't do class inheritance and is nonetheless an OOP language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/258221/are-there-any-oo-languages-without-inheritance#comment523249_258221), then I don't see why VB6/VBA couldn't be considered an OOP language as well. `</PreemptiveResponseToVBAHatersThatWillSayItIsNotAnOOPLanguage>`

Comment: To be fair, OP asked about *modern* languages. =;)-

Comment: @RubberDuck #burn!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the compiler enforce selective inheritance through the use of private / protected, and through modern use of "PImpl", or "Private Implementation" techniques.

Many APIs expose only those components which you would desire a user to inherit, and hide the rest in a separate implementation class.  So you could write classes whose public interfaces are, in fact, uninheritable, only usable through object composition, and compiler-enforced.  This is often good practice, when it uses the compiler to enforce the intent of the software.

A quick search for private member functions in javascript show there is a similar principle, although anybody can see your code if they can use it:
http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html